# Unable to save data to SQLite database using C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, xaml

I am using Visual Studio 2022, with C# and WPF application to create a desktop application. SQLite is the database. Below is the code.

DB Table code

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Disclaimer" (
    "ID"    INTEGER,
    "DisName"   TEXT,
    "DisDateTime"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

App.xaml

```xml
<Application x:Class="Sanganak.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             StartupUri="Splash.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <system:String x:Key="SQLiteConnection">Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Sanganak.db;Version=3;</system:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

C# code behind

```cs
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         // Get the system name
         string systemName = Environment.MachineName;
         // Get the current date and time
         DateTime currentDateAndTime = DateTime.Now;

         // Save data to Sanganak database
         string connectionString = (string)Application.Current.Resources["SQLiteConnection"];
         using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
         {
             connection.Open();
             string sql = "INSERT INTO Disclaimer (DisName, DisDateTime) VALUES (@DisName, @DisDateTime)";
             using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
             {
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisName", systemName);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisDateTime", currentDateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
             connection.Close();
         }
         Hide();
         var setupWindow = new SetUp();
         setupWindow.Show();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         // Log the exception (replace with your actual logging mechanism)
         Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

If I change the name of the table in C# code behind, then I get 'table not found' error. This means the path and connection is correct. But after running the code, if I check the table using DB Browser, it is still empty. the `hide()` and show window work fine. The code either skips the database portion or it updates the table but does not save it. I have tried adding error handlers for `connection.open()` &  `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` but it does not catch an error. The program functions smoothly, just there is no data in the database table.

Comment: `This means the path and connection is correct` no it doesn't. You may be writing to a file in `bin/Debug` but reading from a file in the project's folder

Comment: I am writing to a file which is added to the project from a different folder. But I checked both database files. Data not saved in either files

Comment: The connection string you posted shows a path relative to the application, not another folder. Did you check in `bin/Debug`? That's your application's working directory during debugging

Comment: Yes. I checked the DB file in bin/debug. There is no data present.  I also removed the ID field from the database thinking it might not be working as I am not inserting any value from C# code. Still not working.

Comment: Try using an absolute path instead of `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Sanganak.db;`, to make sure this isn't about the driver. In a desktop application, that's equivalent to just `Data Source=Sanganak.db;` so the database file will be right next to the .exe file.

Comment: Tried 3 locations. Data not save when using any location. 
D:\C#\Sanganak\Sanganak\bin\Debug

D:\C#\Sanganak\Sanganak

C:\Users\athan\Downloads

I did install System.Data.SQLite, System.Data.SQLite.Core, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, System.Data.SQLite.Linq from NuGet Package Manager. And I have added using System.Data.SQLite; above the namespace

Comment: After using Data Source=Sanganak.db, a new db file was created next to exe file, but that is also empty.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a problem in the code. This is the code which actually worked.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the system name
        string systemName = Environment.MachineName;
        // Get the current date and time
        DateTime currentDateAndTime = DateTime.Now;

        // Save data to Sanganak database
        string connectionString = (string)Application.Current.Resources["SQLiteConnection"];
        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to open the SQLite connection.");
            }
            // Now that the connection is open, proceed with the database operation
            string sql = "INSERT INTO Disclaimer (DisName, DisDateTime) VALUES (@DisName, @DisDateTime)";
            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisName", systemName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisDateTime", currentDateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            // No need to close the connection explicitly, as 'using' block takes care of it
        }

        Hide();
        var setupWindow = new SetUp();
        setupWindow.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception (replace with your actual logging mechanism)
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```